# Inject method using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I want to inject one method using Mono.Cecil.

My code is like this:

```
var worker = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
method.Body.Instructions.Clear();//Clear Old code
```

I want to replace the code like:

```
return getCpu();
```

So i write :

```
List<Instruction> listStep = new List<Instruction>();
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));
listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Call,injectMethod));
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_0));
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc_0));
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Br_S));
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_1));
//listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc_1));
listStep.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ret));

foreach (var item in listStep)
{
    worker.Append(item);
}
```

But it didn't work.

I'm confused with IL. Someone can help me? Many thanks.

Comment: How exactly did it not work? What does it do? Have you tried running peverify on the modified assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depend on the original method but maybe you need to add:

```
method.Body.Variables.Clear();
method.Body.ExceptionHandlers.Clear();
```

Also, check that `injectMethod` is a valid method reference.

Now, to inject the method, this should work:

```
worker.Emit(Opcodes.Call, injectMethod);
worker.Emit(Opcodes.Ret);
```

Note, that you emit `call` and not `callvirt`, is this on purpose? Because if `injectMethod` is not a static method, [in most cases](https://mycodingplace.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/call-vs-callvirt-instruction/) you need to emit `callvirt`.